# Group documents by day and count one field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Document example:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5ea773f219d60c4f1629203a"),
        "direction" : 135,
        "latitude" : -3.744851,
        "longitude" : -38.545571,
        "metrictimestamp" : "20180201025959",
        "odometer" : 55697826,
        "routecode" : 0,
        "speed" : 3,
        "deviceid" : 134680,
        "vehicleid" : 32040
```

I need to count how many "vehicleid" is in each day, or, a group by day counting the vehicleid for each one. Please repair that my date is only the first 7 characters of the "metrictimestamp"

Comment: Is this something that you're looking for :: https://mongoplayground.net/p/AqlFPf5kPPo ?

Comment: No, this query is counting how many documents are with the same day, i need to count how many vehicles are stored for that day

Comment: What do you mean by how many vehicles are stored ?

Comment: Each document have a date, and a vehicleid (and other info), i need to count how many different vehicleid is for each day

Comment: Check this : https://mongoplayground.net/p/PhOBr5UU-8o, If this is correct will make it as an answer with description..

Comment: @whoami-fakeFaceTrueSoul This is good stuff. You really should consider adding this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this : mongoplayground.net/p/PhOBr5UU-8o, If this is correct will make it as an answer with description.. – whoami